# How to solve T(n) = 2(T/8) + n using substitution method

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

T(n) = 2(T/8) + n

I have to solve this recurrence by using substitution method and mathematical induction.

using master method, the answer is T(n) = θ(n) by Case 3.

so using substitution method, same answer should be derived. am i right?

Deriving T(n) = O(n) was simple

but when i tried to prove that T(n) = Ω(n) by supposing T(k) >= ck (where k < n)

then T(n) = 2T(n/8) + n >= 1/4*cn + n = cn - (3/4cn - n) >= cn <-- wrong

it's also impossible to solve by subtracting or adding a low-order term

how do i prove that T(n) = θ(n) by using only substitution method?

Answer (score 0):

You can prove T(n) >= n trivially. T(n) = 2T(n/8) + n >= n. You can substitute for 2T(n/8) if you want to make it more complicated, then T(n) = 2T(n/8) + n >= n/4 + n >= n.

I haven't looked closely at your proof, but it seems like you're assuming that you can prove it for all c, rather than for some particular c (in my proof, c=1). Maybe that over-ambitious assumption is causing you trouble.

Comment: thank you for answering. I thought the inequality had to be satisfied with all c>0

Comment: @Gagasbandas looking at the definition of Omega or Theta is helpful